# Parsing string containing backslahes

Tags: c#, json.net

How can i parse the following string to json object in C#:

```
string unescapedstring = " {"SettingName":"name","SettingValue":"\\log1\\log2\\","Description":"description"}"
```

to get:

```
  {
    "SettingName": "name",
    "SettingValue": "\\log1\\log2\\",
    "Description": "description"
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: where does unescapedstring come from?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in a sentence exactly what you want to happen. You want to format a JSON? What? This Q is unclear.

Comment: For lack of clarification from OP, I don't see anything differentiating this question from the [many others on the site](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+parse+json+site%3Astackoverflow.com) that ask about parsing JSON. Closed.

Comment: I'm passing this string :  "{\"SettingName\":\"name\",\"SettingValue\":\"\\\\log1\\\\lo‌​g2\\\\\", \"Description\":\"description\"} actualy this is an object as a parameter via ajax call to a function whitch save the object in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JObject` class and its method `.parse` which accepts string as argument:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(unescapedstring);
```

**[Newtonsoft_Json Library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm)**

Comment: the string unescapedstring has a value as "{\"SettingName\":\"name\",\"SettingValue\":\"\\\\log1\\\\log2\\\\\", \"Description\":\"description\"}